# "Csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Everytime I try to run my code, I am having this error that **"Csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819**
, I cleaned my solution and restarted Visual Studio with no gain.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: -1073741819 indicates an Access Violation. Try to start Visual Studio with Administrator rights

Comment: It is not that kind of "access", it is a hard crash of the compiler.  First check that a "Hello world" program can still be compiled.  If it does then go back to your original program and comment out chunks of code until the crash disappears.

Comment: Same code got compile first, but next time it is giving this error. Strange

Comment: Just restarting Visual Studio solved it in my case.

Answer (score 8):

I faced same problem. Delete the bin and obj folder in project(s). The try to clean and rebuild the solution. This worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me on VS Community 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1, .Net version 4.6.1038.

Answer (score 6):

Cleaning and rebuilding the solution will sometimes solve the issue and sometimes won't.

You need to repair Visual Studio. Go to **Control Panel** -> **Programs**. Then select your version of Visual Studio you are using and press "**Change**"(or right click it and press "**Change**"). When the setup appears, click "**Repair**".

This solved it for me and several others who have been facing this issue.

Comment: Clean, rebuild worked for me. This started to happen after power cut off in the midle of debug.

Comment: Repairing .Net 4.7 Framework worked for me - VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

For the problem `csc-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819`

I repaired `Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)`. This worked for me.[repair Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCCz4.png). I found about this problem when uninstalling and then reinstalling `VS2015`. After the setup is completed it says that some items are not installed correctly. And among them is **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015** not installed correctly.

So after a while I repaired **Visual C++ Redistributable 2015**. Here is the link [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Answer (score 1):

1. classic ms solution: restart computer :D
2. delete bin and obj folders
3. open vs
4. build

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience here because I had this problem for several days (with VS Studio 2012) and I had MANY MANY difficulties to find the solution !

And my problem was... That I had a virus/malware problem, and the faulty module was BITGUARD !

So if someone has this problem, and goes here searching the solution, I think you must try any free Malware remover program to see if Bitguard should not be your problem !

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and luckily found a solution.

First off is more of a workaround, but seemed to work. Disable parallel build in Visual Studio
(Tools -> Options ->Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. Change maximum number of parallel builds to 1).
This resolved the issue for me, but did not solve the problem.

The issue I had, as obscure as it is, was I had Razer Synapse set up to record mouse and keyboard stats on Visual Studio. Once I disabled this, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately the build and run workaround you suggested to me didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

When our company changed anti-virus software, an application that had not been touched in months suddenly started having the build error
`"csc.exe" exited with code -532462766.`.

I used our new AV client to scan the bin folder of the application that wouldn't build. The AV client claimed it was infected with **W32.Trojan.Genkd**. Uninstalling that AV software allowed it to build as usual. I think a single file got quarantined, preventing the build.

Your options may be these:

- disinfect the files (assuming it's an actual infection)
- unquarantine the "infected" files (assuming it's actually safe)
- uninstall / disable that AV client
- change AV software

Lastly, you could always comment blocks of code to identify what is causing the false-positive.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running from the devenv command. Adding `/SafeMode` to the command arguments solved my issue which lead me to think one of my install extension/plugins for VS2015 was to blame.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved the same issue by **Restarting my PC** and that's it.